# Jekyll and pygments using nasm

Tags: jekyll, pygments, redcarpet

I'm trying to get my nasm syntax highlighted in Jekyll using pygments. It works flawlessly for C and Python, but nasm doesn't seem to work.

````
```nasm
  section .text
       global _start
  _start:
       xor ecx, ecx
       mov al,15   ; changed push pop to mov
       push ecx
       push byte 0x77
       mov cx,0x4d42 ; random addition before pushing
       add cx,0x2222
       push cx
       push 0x6168732f
       push 0x6374652f
       mov ebx, esp
       push word 0x1b6
       pop ecx
       int 0x80</p>
           mov al,1  ; changed push pop to mov
       int 0x80
```
````

Instead of embedding everything in span tags it just produces this:

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-nasm" data-lang="nasm">  section .text
       global _start
  _start:
       xor ecx, ecx
       mov al,15   ; changed push pop to mov
       push ecx
       push byte 0x77
       mov cx,0x4d42 ; random addition before pushing
       add cx,0x2222
       push cx
       push 0x6168732f
       push 0x6374652f
       mov ebx, esp
       push word 0x1b6
       pop ecx
       int 0x80&lt;/p&gt;
       mov al,1  ; changed push pop to mov
       int 0x80
</code></pre></div>
```

This is my _config.yml:

```
name: "Cloud101"
description: "Blog"
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
url: "http://cloud101.eu"

paginate: 10
markdown: redcarpet


syntax_highlighter: pygments
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "strikethrough", "superscript"]
```

Comment: What does `{{ site.highlighter }}` outputs ? Because `syntax_highlighter` doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidJacquel that was the issue, thanks ^^